# zsh completion: Disable ssh username completion

Tags: ssh, autocomplete, zsh

I am using the completion scripts that ship with ZSH (5.7.1) and I would like to turn off the autocompletion for usernames, but keep the completion for hostnames.

How can I do this?

Currently, there's an erroneous user that I can't figure out why it's being included (not in ~/.ssh/config, any identities, /etc/ssh, or any other location) and I figure it's probably easier to just disable username completion.

Example output is below; I want to remove the entire "login name" section rather than try and hunt down where unwanted-username is coming from.

```
$ ssh <tab>
 -- login name --
unwanted-username
 -- host --
example-host-1      example-host-1
```

I expect there is a `zstyle` command which can disable it, but I'm not sure the correct incantation.  I expect this is the relevant configuration that needs to be changed:

```
$ zstyle | grep completion | grep ssh
        :completion:*:ssh:* users hosts-domain hosts-host users hosts-ipaddr
```

However, I can't seem to get the correct incantation to remove the `login name` section.

Answer (score 4):

To disable completion of login names, in that context, try:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:argument-1:*' tag-order hosts
```

or to merely hide them, try:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:users' hidden true
```

Pressing `Ctrl-X h` instead of `tab` is a good way to determine the relevant tags and context strings.

Seems odd that you have an erroneous user being completed. Check for a `users-hosts` style being set, possibly without mention of `ssh` in the context. The `ignored-patterns` style could be another way to deal with an erroneous match in the general case, for example:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:users' ignored-patterns erroneous-username
```

As you might discern from the name of the style, the last argument here can be a shell pattern with `*`, `?` etc.

Comment: The first line with `hidden true` doesn't work for me unfortunately.  For the debugging info via `Ctrl-X H`, this does not work for me on macOS.  I tried all of the modifier keys (Cmd, Opt, Ctrl) and couldn't get this to work.  I know I've made it work in the past.

Comment: If `Ctrl-X h` doesn't work, you can instead try pressing `Alt+x` and entering the command `_complete_help` in the "execute:" prompt that should appear below your normal prompt line.

Comment: Do you perhaps do `bindkey -e` or `bindkey -v` *after* running compinit? Normally compinit adds the binding to whatever keymap  is current.

Comment: Execute `compinit` manually just before entering the command you want to debug completions for. That worked for me (macOS) - after that `Ctrl+X H` prints completion debug info for the current line buffer.